# Params.list() providing incorrect values

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm trying to get a list of ids from my params, but when I read them, I end up with different values than the expected values. Expected values are 2 and 8, I'm ending up with 50 and 56. Does anybody know where these results are coming from?

Code

```
println 'Params ' + params
Long[] departments = params.list('departmentIds');
println 'departmentIds ' + departments
```

Output

```
Params [start:2016-02-28, departmentIds:[2, 8], end:2016-04-10, action:calendarRequest, format:json, controller:calendar]
departmentIds [50, 56]
```

Comment: Those are the ascii values of the characters '2' and '8'.

Comment: Ah okay, makes sense now. Any idea how I could retrieve and convert to a list of longs?

Comment: I think it is trying to convert those 'chars' to numbers when you assign to `Long[]`.  You might `def departments = ...` to keep 2 and 8 as strings/chars.

Comment: Retrieve as list of strings then `Long.parseLong(value)` on each value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
println 'Params ' + params
Long[] departments = params.list('departmentIds').collect { Long.parseLong(it) }
println 'departmentIds ' + departments
```

Or something like that...

Comment: Beautiful solution, you have to love grails. Thanks.

Comment: Groovy is my favorite language for getting stuff done on the JVM.

Comment: I'm relatively new to groovy/grails coming from java and I can't believe all the things you can do with it.

Comment: Yep!  It's AWESOME and the community is very nice.  Ken Kousen has some good videos on Groovy available on O'Reilley media.  http://search.oreilly.com/?q=Groovy&x=0&y=0.  Venkat Subramaniam's book on Groovy 2 is a good conversational book on the language.  Dave Klein's Grails 2 Quickstart is a gentle introduction to Grails if you want that.